# converting xtensor xarray to opencv mat back and forth in cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, python-xarray, opencv-mat, xtensor

I am looking for a fast and reliable way to convert `xt::xarray <-> cv::mat / cv::mat1f`.
In my specific case, I what it for 2 dimensions and datatype float, but more general answers are welcome, of course!

At the moment, I have an elementwise solution.
This is quite robust, but I would appreciate a faster one.
I have some trouble to implement [this](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/issues/1286) one.

**Elementwise solutions**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xadapt.hpp"


cv::Mat xarray_to_mat_elementwise(xt::xarray<float> xarr)
{
    int ndims = xarr.dimension();
    assert(ndims == 2  && "can only convert 2d xarrays");
    int nrows = xarr.shape()[0];
    int ncols = xarr.shape()[1];
    cv::Mat mat(nrows, ncols, CV_32FC1);
    for (int rr=0; rr<nrows; rr++)
    {
        for (int cc=0; cc<ncols; cc++)
        {
            mat.at<float>(rr, cc) = xarr(rr, cc);
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

xt::xarray<float> mat_to_xarray_elementwise(cv::Mat mat)
{
    int ndims = mat.dims;
    assert(ndims == 2  && "can only convert 2d xarrays");
    int nrows = mat.rows;
    int ncols = mat.cols;
    xt::xarray<float> xarr = xt::empty<float>({nrows, ncols});
    for (int rr=0; rr<nrows; rr++)
    {
        for (int cc=0; cc<ncols; cc++)
        {
            xarr(rr, cc) = mat.at<float>(rr, cc);
        }
    }
    return xarr;
}



int main()
{
    int nrows = 2, ncols = 3;
    float data[150];
    for (int i=0; i<nrows * ncols; i++)
    {
        data[i] = .1 * i;
    }

    cv::Mat mat (nrows, ncols, CV_32FC1, data, 0);
    std::cout << "mat:\n" << mat << std::endl;

    xt::xarray<float> xarr = xt::adapt(
        (float*) data, nrows * ncols, xt::no_ownership(), std::vector<std::size_t> {nrows, ncols});
    std::cout << "xarr:\n" << xarr << std::endl;

    cv::Mat mat2_ew = xarray_to_mat_elementwise(xarr);
    std::cout << "mat2_ew (from xt::xarray):\n" << mat2_ew << std::endl;

    xt::xarray<float> xarr2_ew = mat_to_xarray_elementwise(mat);
    std::cout << "xarr2_ew (from cv::mat):\n" << xarr2_ew << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
mat:
[0, 0.1, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]
xarr:
{{ 0.      ,  0.1     ,  0.2     },
 { 0.3     ,  0.4     ,  0.5     }}
mat2_ew (from xt::xarray):
[0, 0.1, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]
xarr2_ew (from cv::mat):
{{ 0.      ,  0.1     ,  0.2     },
 { 0.3     ,  0.4     ,  0.5     }}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution based on pointers**

This converts `xt::xarray <-> cv::mat(1f)` based on the pointers to the underlying data of the source object. No copying of data is necessary, but deallocation of the memory may be necessary.

> Pointer to the user data. Matrix constructors that take data and step
> parameters do not allocate matrix data. Instead, they just initialize
> the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that
> no data is copied. This operation is very efficient and can be used to
> process external data using OpenCV functions. The external data is not
> automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.

Compare the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a).

**Do not use call by value, when converting:**
If wrapping the converter in a function (compare `xarray_to_mat`), be carefull to use a call by reference.
Otherwise the pointer `xarr.data()` is pointing to a non-allocated memory position.

**xt::layout_type::column_major:**
Of course the `column_major layout` in xtensor makes some trouble.
Maybe it makes sense to fall back to the `elementwise assignment` in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xadapt.hpp"

/**
 * Converts xt::xarray to cv::mat.
 *
 * First few elements are wrong (not reproducible).
 * This can be repaired by using call by reference: xt::xarray<float> xarr -> xt::xarray<float> & xarr
 */
cv::Mat xarray_to_mat(xt::xarray<float> xarr)
{
    cv::Mat mat (xarr.shape()[0], xarr.shape()[1], CV_32FC1, xarr.data(), 0);
    return mat;
}

xt::xarray<float> mat_to_xarray(cv::Mat mat)
{
    xt::xarray<float> res = xt::adapt(
        (float*) mat.data, mat.cols * mat.rows, xt::no_ownership(), std::vector<std::size_t> {mat.rows, mat.cols});
    return res;
}

cv::Mat xarray_to_mat_elementwise(xt::xarray<float> xarr)
{
    int ndims = xarr.dimension();
    assert(ndims == 2  && "can only convert 2d xarrays");
    int nrows = xarr.shape()[0];
    int ncols = xarr.shape()[1];
    cv::Mat mat(nrows, ncols, CV_32FC1);
    for (int rr=0; rr<nrows; rr++)
    {
        for (int cc=0; cc<ncols; cc++)
        {
            mat.at<float>(rr, cc) = xarr(rr, cc);
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

xt::xarray<float> mat_to_xarray_elementwise(cv::Mat mat)
{
    int ndims = mat.dims;
    assert(ndims == 2  && "can only convert 2d xarrays");
    int nrows = mat.rows;
    int ncols = mat.cols;
    xt::xarray<float> xarr = xt::empty<float>({nrows, ncols});
    for (int rr=0; rr<nrows; rr++)
    {
        for (int cc=0; cc<ncols; cc++)
        {
            xarr(rr, cc) = mat.at<float>(rr, cc);
        }
    }
    return xarr;
}

int main()
{
    int nrows = 2, ncols = 3;
    float data[150];
    for (int i=0; i<nrows * ncols; i++)
    {
        data[i] = .1 * i;
    }

    cv::Mat mat (nrows, ncols, CV_32FC1, data, 0);
    std::cout << "mat:\n" << mat << std::endl;

    xt::xarray<float> xarr = xt::adapt(
        (float*) data, nrows * ncols, xt::no_ownership(), std::vector<std::size_t> {nrows, ncols});
    std::cout << "xarr:\n" << xarr << std::endl;

    cv::Mat mat2 (nrows, ncols, CV_32FC1, xarr.data(), 0);
    std::cout << "mat2 (from xt::xarray, works):\n" << mat2 << std::endl;

    cv::Mat mat3 = xarray_to_mat(xarr);
    std::cout << "mat3 (from xt::xarray, call by value -> fails):\n" << mat3 << std::endl;

    xt::xarray<float> xarr2 = mat_to_xarray(mat);
    std::cout << "xarr2 (from cv::mat):\n" << xarr2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n=========== works for cv::mat1f analoguous ===========\n" << std::endl;

    cv::Mat1f mat_1f (nrows, ncols, data, 0);
    std::cout << "mat_1f:\n" << mat_1f << std::endl;

    cv::Mat1f mat_1f_2 (nrows, ncols, (float*) xarr.data(), 0);
    std::cout << "mat_1f_2 (from xt::xarray, works):\n" << mat_1f_2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n=========== column_major layout in xtensor ===========\n" << std::endl;

    xt::xarray<float, xt::layout_type::column_major> xarr_cm = xt::adapt(
        (float*) data, nrows * ncols, xt::no_ownership(), std::vector<std::size_t> {nrows, ncols});
    std::cout << "xarr_cm:\n" << xarr_cm << std::endl;

    cv::Mat mat_cm (nrows, ncols, CV_32FC1, xarr_cm.data(), 0);
    std::cout << "mat_cm (from xt::xarray, pointer based -> fails):\n" << mat_cm << std::endl;

    cv::Mat mat_cm_ew = xarray_to_mat_elementwise(xarr_cm);
    std::cout << "mat_cm_ew (from xt::xarray, elementwise -> works):\n" << mat_cm_ew << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

** output **

```
mat:
[0, 0.1, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]
xarr:
{{ 0.      ,  0.1     ,  0.2     },
 { 0.3     ,  0.4     ,  0.5     }}
mat2 (from xt::xarray, works):
[0, 0.1, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]
mat3 (from xt::xarray, call by value -> fails):
[4.3654774e-38, 0, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]
xarr2 (from cv::mat):
{{ 0.      ,  0.1     ,  0.2     },
 { 0.3     ,  0.4     ,  0.5     }}

=========== works for cv::mat1f analoguous ===========

mat_1f:
[0, 0.1, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]
mat_1f_2 (from xt::xarray, works):
[0, 0.1, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]

=========== column_major layout in xtensor ===========

xarr_cm:
{{ 0.      ,  0.1     ,  0.2     },
 { 0.3     ,  0.4     ,  0.5     }}
mat_cm (from xt::xarray, pointer based -> fails):
[0, 0.30000001, 0.1;
 0.40000001, 0.2, 0.5]
mat_cm_ew (from xt::xarray, elementwise -> works):
[0, 0.1, 0.2;
 0.30000001, 0.40000001, 0.5]
```

Comment: When I try mat_to_xarray I get the following problem: [build] /usr/local/include/xtensor/xexpression.hpp:168:88: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
[build]          xtl::disjunction< std::is_base_of<B<E>, F<E>>, std::is_base_of<B<F<E>>, F<E>>> {};

where the input image was generated from OpenCV: cv::Mat image = cv::imread(path);

Answer (score 0):

If the Mat passed to `mat_to_xarray` is not a float then the cast will be bad.. Converting the Mat to the same data type as your cast might make things a little safer. `mat.convertTo(mat, CV_32F);`